# Ionic Google Maps Marker Window content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to implement angular-google-maps markers in my ionic app, complete with info windows that will contain some simple html and a button to take you to the pin's 'profile'.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Local Users">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Local Users</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content scroll="false" data-tap-disabled="true">
            <ui-gmap-google-map id="map" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
                <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in arrayOfMarkers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" ng-click="toggleInfoWindow" idkey="marker.id">
                    <ui-gmap-window>
                        <div><h3>{{marker.name}}</h3><button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="viewProfile" id="marker.sid">View Profile</button></div>
                    </ui-gmap-window>
                </ui-gmap-marker>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</ion-view>
```

Relevant code in the Controller:

```
function renderAllUsers(results) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
                var user = results[i];
                var mySID = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("userObject")).userProfileId;
                if (user.userProfileId != mySID) {
                    var userCoords = {
                        latitude: user.userProfileLatitude,
                        longitude: user.userProfileLongitude
                    };
                    var markerOptions = {
                        animation: "drop"
                    }
                    var thisMarker = {
                        id:i,
                        coords: userCoords,
                        name: userObject.userProfileName,
                        sid: userObject.id,
                        options: markerOptions,
                        idKey: i,
                        window: {
                            show: false,
                            title: "Hello"
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.arrayOfMarkers.push(thisMarker);
                }
            }
        }

        $scope.toggleInfoWindow = function () {
            $scope.windowOptions.visible = !$scope.windowOptions.visible;
        };

        $scope.viewProfile = function (e) {
            $state.go("app.userProfile");
        };
```

Using the code outlined, the button click does nothing, with no errors logged.

Any advice?

Comment: I believe I might need to do some sort of binding? I've done this in normal HTML & GMaps API but not using the Angular-Google-Maps package

Answer (score 0):

It probably occurs since `viewProfile` event declared in controller scope is not accessible from the `ui-gmap-window` child scope.

The following solution worked for me:

First we need to introduce an additional controller:

```
app.controller('infoWindowCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.viewProfile = function (e) {
        alert("app.userProfile");
    }
});
```

and then change info window layout to:

```
 <ui-gmap-window>
     <div ng-controller="infoWindowCtrl">
          <h3>{{marker.name}}</h3>
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="viewProfile($event)" id="marker.sid">View Profile</button>
     </div>
 </ui-gmap-window>
```

[**Demo (plunker)**](https://plnkr.co/edit/k2oefZ3ACgdilrLwuPmA?p=preview)